# Pokemon transferring

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-series

If you transfer your Pokemon from one game to another, like let's say from Soul Silver to Black 2, will the Pokemon that were transferred be yours in the Black 2 game or the other games Pokemon? I'm asking this because I have a different name in my Soul Silver game than in my Black 2 game.

Comment: Even if the name is the same, the trainer ID will still be different, I would expect.

Answer (score 9):

No. Pokemon "ownership" is based on both the trainer's name and the original trainer ID which is a random 5-digit number (assigned when you start your game). Both values can be seen in a Pokemon's summary screen.

So even with the same name, the chance of having the same ID Number is extremely small.

Comment: FYI: The original trainer ID actually is two 5-digit numbers (one that is public and one that is hidden) so ID duplicates are even more unlikely

Answer (score -1):

As I recall, having transferred all of my Pokémon from Gen IV games into Black, they're under the name of your character in Black. I'll confirm this when I'm not in work.

EDIT: Checked while in work ("Code compiling."). I was mistaken: I used the same Trainer Name in Gen IV, but the Trainer ID was different. So, it retains those, but converts the Pokémon. So, @DisgruntledGoat got it right.